# Node JS mongoose cannot connect to remote mongodb server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The script inside VM **192.168.26.103** is trying to connect to MongoDB on VM **192.168.26.104**

But getting **'ECONNREFUSED'** error

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var dbConnect = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://192.168.26.104:27017/test', {
    db: { safe: true }
})
```

**Error:**

```
{ name: 'MongoError', message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED' }
```

Comment: Try to connect in shell(command prompt). if its not k ,then there is some problem in configuration.

Comment: @Subburaj i can successfully ssh to that server and run mongo command

Comment: Whether mongo is running on default port in server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue myself. Posting the solution below so someone might find helpfull.

In remote MongoDB server 192.168.26.104 i changed the bind_ip and now my script can connect to it successfully

```
/etc/mongod.conf
```

From `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1`

To `bind_ip = 192.168.26.104`

```
service mongod restart
```